# Parshiot names together & meaning

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, names, commentaries

I'm looking for sources and mefarshim that dealt with the Parshiot names and their meanings, not only for a single Parsha name alone, but all the Parshiot names of the Torah together or of a Sefer.

Meaning, does a sentence with the Parshiot names as "Bereshit Noach Lech (Lecha) Vayera Chayei (Sara) Toldot Vayetzei Vayishlach Vayeshev Miketz Vayigash Vayechi" have any significance?

Gut Shabbos

Comment: The Lubavitcher Rebbe often spoke about the signficance of the Parsha names, and that though they're only colloquial, they carry meaning because מנהג ישראל תורה היא. But I don't know if he explained all of them or whether they're compiled anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The [Gutnick Chumash](https://www.mitzvahland.com/products/chumash-the-gutnick-edition-synagogue-edition-kol-menachem) has a short introduction before each parsha discussing the name according to chassidus. Here's a sample:
[image: Gutnick Chumash]